# Javascript / iPhone - How do I resize the browser viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

How do I dynamically resize the viewport for iOS devices? I'm using jQuery to append the viewport meta tag. But only resizes the viewport once. Modifying the content attribute via attr('content', 'width=newwidth') which doesn't work (its jquery 1.5, prior to attr()/prop() change)

**Example:**

```
// This works once
$('head').append($('<meta name="viewport" content="width=640; user-scalable=no">'));

// Does not work
$meta.attr('content', 'width=1024; user-scalable=no');
```

Answer (score 1):

$meta.attr('content', 'width=1024; user-scalable=no');

missed your colon dude

Comment: Ah cutting mistake :x, accidentally chopped off the semicolon from the original code: $meta.attr('content', 'width=' + width + '; user-scalable=no');

Comment: comment vote ;). I'm waiting for a solution to fixed question.